# Getting Birthdays worldwide with time difference and DST

Tags: sql-server

I have a user table with a birthday field and I am trying to get all the user ids where their birthday is today. The hard part is to account for time difference between countries and DST.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE MONTH(Birthday) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND DAY(Birthday) BETWEEN DAY(GETDATE()) - 2 AND DAY(GETDATE()) + 2
```

I am including the -/+ 2 days to make sure I have birthdays for people who might be several hours ahead of or behind our server time. I'm not sure where to go from here.

How can I make sure I get the right users?

**EDIT:**
I am using SQL Server 2005 and know the location of a user based on their bill country.

Comment: Are you also storing the users geographic location?  If you use GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) combined with the users location, you could send it right at midnight where it is for them.

Comment: You definitely need to know the GeoLocation or the TimeZone of the Users. Are you storing that somewhere in your Users table?

Comment: We have a bill country that we use to determine their location. Some also have a bill state, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to work it out using datetiemoffset:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The example below creates a test table in [tempdb] that has 48 hours of dates.

If my server is running on GMT time, I can convert all the dates stored in the table to GMT by using the offsetting to zero the constant.

```
-- Just playing around
use tempdb;
go

-- A simple table with dates
create table my_birthday
(
  -- simple id
  my_id int identity(1,1) primary key,

  -- store date with offset
  my_date datetimeoffset
);

-- Data with GMT offset
declare @cnt int = -48;
while @cnt < 49
begin
  insert into my_birthday (my_date) values ( DATEADD(HH, -@cnt, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) );
  set @cnt += 1;
end;

-- Pick todays data
select * from my_birthday 
where datediff(d, my_date, switchoffset(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2013-12-12'), '+00:00') ) = 0
```

Looking at the output, we get 5 extra days on 12-11 since I am in the EST time zone and loose 5 days at the end of day.  But we still only get 24 hours which is correct.

**In short, you need the datetimeoffset data type and the switchoffset() function for this solution.**

[image]

Comment: The birthdays for the users are stored as dates without a timestamp or timezone, but that would have made things a lot easier. So converting them to the server time has no benefit. The only place I can think of getting any correlation is with their bill country.

Comment: Add an additional column or table with a datetimeoffset.  Adjust the time zone by country.  Then you will be the HERO of the day!